# Dynamic menu and titles in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, tags

For example, I have 2 pages, left menu and use for layout tags. Tag for left menu:

```
<%@tag description="Left panel" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@attribute name="page" required="true"%>
<ul>
    <!-- Dashboard -->
    <li <c:if test="${page == 'dashboard'}">class="active"</c:if>>
       <a href="<c:url value='/dashboard'/>">           
            <spring:message code="navigation.button.dashboard"/>
       </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Settings -->
    <li <c:if test="${page == 'settings'}">class="active"</c:if>>
       <a href="<c:url value='/settings/'/>">
            <spring:message code="navigation.button.settings"/>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For view active menu i am use variable page and in all my spring controller i set this model attribute, for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings")
public final class SettingController {    
    @ModelAttribute("page")
    public final String getPage() { return "settings";}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public final String home(final Principal principal) {
        if (principal == null) return "login";
        return "settings";
    }
}
```

For title of page i used page attribute too. I think this is not the best way. Maybe anyone knows about best way for dynamic view active menu and title of page?